How does "Pasch axiom" in Tarski geometry relate to the usual Pasch axiom?
In Tarski's axiomatization of planar geometry (see here and there), there is an axiom called "Pasch axiom" and formulated as:
$(Bxuz \land Byvz) \rightarrow \exists a\, (Buay \land Bvax)$
This, interpreted on a figure ($B$ being the symbol for betweenness), gives the following:

I fail to see how this relates to the usual formulation of Pasch axiom (found for instance in Hilbert's axioms), which states that, if ABC is a triangle and L a line not containing any of A, B, C, if L intersects AB (on D) then it must intersect BC or AC (on E) as seen below:

My question is: how does Tarski's "Pasch axiom" relate to the usual formulation of Pasch axiom. In particular, is there an obvious way to deduce one from the other in the context of euclidean geometry, which I may have missed?

Hilbert's version says that if a line intersects one of the sides of a triangle, it should intersect one of the two other sides. This is true only in 2D. So, one needs another assumption stating the line lies in the plane of the triangle.
Tarski's version of Pasch's axiom is more precise than Hilbert's version:
it tells you which side it will intersect the triangle and is valid in any dimension.
In Tarski's version, triangle ABC is the triangle $xvz$. The line is the line $uy$, we know it intersects side $xz$ in $u$, the axiom says it intersects side $xv$ in $a$, assuming it was not intersecting side $vz$ (Byvs).
It is also more general, because the degenerate case of Tarski's version when the triangle is flat, provides some properties about betweenness, whereas Hilbert's version assumes the triangle is not degenerated.
We have formalized in Coq the proof that the axiom systems of Tarski and Hilbert are bi-interpretable, this includes a proof that you can recover one version of Pasch from the other, it is not completely trivial because of degenerated cases.
Here is one paper (but it does not give details about the proofs):
https://inria.hal.science/hal-01332044/file/hilbert_to_tarski.pdf
The machine-checkable proofs are here:
https://geocoq.github.io/GeoCoq/html/GeoCoq.Meta_theory.Models.hilbert_to_tarski.html
and here:
https://geocoq.github.io/GeoCoq/html/GeoCoq.Meta_theory.Models.tarski_to_hilbert.html
Sorry, they are not very human-readable...

Very clear, and interesting, thank you!
